# Logic, Language and Proof - please help me with 14.13 (Fitch)

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, solution-verification

I'm not sure how to get line 23... to solve make all my a = e and b = d

Also, thank you to everyone who has helped me out before!!! I grately appreciate it :)

[image]

Comment: See [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/68650/lpl-fitch-proof-exercise-14-13-help)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA hey, do you mind sending a photo of the page? I can't seem to access it :/

Answer (score 2):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\def\C#1{\operatorname{Cube}(#1)}$ You have realised that you must use three arbitrary variables to introduce three universal quantifiers.

Well, you should *use* them.   Eliminate the universal statement $\forall z~(\C z\to z=a\vee z=b)$ to *each* instance: $c, d, e$, to derive *three* conditional statements, then use the assumption to derive *three* disjunctions.

From there you may nest proof by cases to derive the target disjunction.   Note that the purpose of *identity elimination* in this is to 'eliminate' the variables $a$ and $b$.

$$\small\fitch{\exists x~\exists y~(\C x\wedge \C y\wedge x\neq y\wedge\forall z~(\C z\to z=x\vee z=y))}{\fitch{\boxed a~\exists y~(\C a\wedge \C y\wedge a\neq y\wedge\forall z~(\C z\to z=a\vee z=y))}{\fitch{\boxed b~\C a\wedge \C b\wedge a\neq b\wedge\forall z~(\C z\to z=a\vee z= b)}{\C a\\\C b\\ a\neq b\\\forall z~(\C z\to z=a\vee z=b)\\\fitch{\boxed e}{\fitch{\boxed d}{\fitch{\boxed e}{\C c\to c=a\vee c=b\\\C d\to d=a\vee d=b\\\C e\to e=a\vee e=b\\\fitch{\C c\wedge\C d\wedge\C e}{\C c\\\C d\\\C e\\c=a\vee c=b\\d=a\vee d=b\\e=a\vee e=b\\\fitch{c=a}{\fitch {d=a}{c=d\\c=d\vee c=e\vee d=e}\\\fitch{d=b}{~~\vdots\\c=d\vee c=e\vee d=e}\\c=d\vee c=e\vee d=e}\\\fitch{c=b}{~~\vdots\\c=d\vee c=e\vee d=e}\\c=d\vee c=e\vee d=e}\\ \C c\wedge\C d\wedge\C e\to c=d\vee c=e\vee c=d}\\\forall z~(\C c\wedge\C d\wedge\C z\to c=d\vee c=z\vee d=z)}\\\forall y~\forall z~(\C c\wedge\C y\wedge\C z\to c=y\vee c=z\vee y=z)}\\\forall x~\forall y~\forall z~(\C x\wedge\C y\wedge\C z\to x=y\vee x=z\vee y=z)\\ \exists y~(\C a\wedge\C y\wedge a\neq y)\\\exists x~\exists y~(\C x\wedge\C y\wedge x\neq y)\\ \exists x~\exists y~(\C x\wedge\C y\wedge x\neq y)\wedge \forall x~\forall y~\forall z~(\C x\wedge\C y\wedge\C z\to x=y\vee x=z\vee y=z)}\\ \exists x~\exists y~(\C x\wedge\C y\wedge x\neq y)\wedge \forall x~\forall y~\forall z~(\C x\wedge\C y\wedge\C z\to x=y\vee x=z\vee y=z)}\\ \exists x~\exists y~(\C x\wedge\C y\wedge x\neq y)\wedge \forall x~\forall y~\forall z~(\C x\wedge\C y\wedge\C z\to x=y\vee x=z\vee y=z)}$$

Comment: Ohh wow, i see how it is done, thank you so much Graham!